# Special Case to Replace String Using Python with Regex

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to replace decimal point but not period in one content.

For example:

Original Content:

```
This is a cake. It is 1.45 dollars and 2.38 kg.
```

Replaced Content:

```
This is a cake. It cost 1<replace>45 dollars and 2<replace>38 kg.
```

How can I use Python Regex to do it ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) with lookaround assertions:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'This is a cake. It is 1.45 dollars and 2.38 kg.'
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=\d)\.(?=\d)', '<replace>', s)
'This is a cake. It is 1<replace>45 dollars and 2<replace>38 kg.'
```

Comment: What is the meaning of ?<=, I know ?=

Comment: @Jimmy, `(?<=\d)\.` means `.` is preceded by digit (`\d`). It's called positive look behind  assertion.

Comment: @Jimmy, Find `(?<=...)` from [Regular expression syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).